# Appcelerator Studio OSX, tries to install Node and Fails

Tags: appcelerator-studio

Having removed NODE, NPM and Appcelerator Studio and re-installed the lot, I can not launch the Studio without it attempting to Install node - it then fails (see image in link).

```
MacBook-Pro:MacOS timfisher$ node -v
```

v4.2.0

This is on a MacBook Pro running HighSierra - any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zybXO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something going wrong in installing node by the studio.

Can you install Node v6.9.0 (LTS) and launch studio. 4.2.0 is the minimum required version for Studio 4.10.0